# Concurrency control with php /ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Assuming a situation like this, a page with simple form input phone number and it allow multi user - access:

```
<form>
Name: * <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Phone: (if any) <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
</form>
```

The **phone** field in database is pre-defined as **allow-null**.
The problem is when **user A** inputting the form , **user B** modify the database and set **phone** field as **not-null** . When user A submit , the phone will be a null value and post to the mysql database.

What i want to achieve is , if that field is modifyied to non-null, it should refresh before submit, retrieve the database structure before submit. Once there is difference, it return to the form and display like the following

```
<form>
Name: * <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Phone: * <input type="text" name="phone" /> Sorry. You have to enter phone number<br />
</form>
```

How can it implement base on php(if possible)/ ajax? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite weird to implement any refresh before submit and make decisions on browser side.

Such a situation should be checked on PHP side (after submit), which should return an error result-code meaning "The field is not null any more, please provide a value"

Comment: The important part  is differentiate between the situation 1) it is predefined null   and 2) it is define as null during the userA input. How can it implemented? thanks

Comment: Why do you need this ? From your comment i understand, that "user may write null only when field is null, if field is not null any more - it can never be null-ed again". correct me if i'm wrong or give better explaination of your case.